# Azure resize and lose password

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have a classic Azure VM running Ubuntu 14.04. It was running in an Standard A0 (1 Core, 0.75 GB memory) and I resized to Standard A2 using the Web portal.

After the resize the SSH didn't work anymore. It warned of changed keys and after I removed the entry from known hosts it connected to the session but didn't accept the password for the `azureuser` account.

I tried to reset the password using:

```
azure vm extension set compilemachine "VMAccessForLinux" "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" 
"1.*" -r "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux"
```

But the CLI doesn't work due to lack if Provision Guest Agent

```
info:    Executing command vm extension set
+ Getting virtual machines
error:   Provision Guest Agent must be enabled on the VM before setting VM Extension.
error:   Error information has been recorded to /Users/user/.azure/azure.err
error:   vm extension set command failed
```

Any hints on how to recover the data from the VM? Or to recover the access to the VM?

Comment: If the server key changed, the server changed.  Did the resize change the IP address of your server and you're still trying to connect to the old server?

Comment: to the old server. Something is weird with resizing.

Comment: Check if you were assigned a different IP.  If the IP you're trying to connect to didn't have your server key, it's not your server.

Answer (score 2):

In a pinch, you can download the virtual hard disk for the VM and mount it on any Windows system (or attach it to a Hyper-V virtual machine).

Answer (score 0):

We can use this script to reset password:
1. create a .json file, like this:

```
{
  "username": "azureuser",
  "password": "newpassword"
}
```

then save it on your PC.
2. login azure with CLI:

```
azure login
azure config mode asm
azure vm extension set ubuntu VMAccessForLinux Microsoft.OSTCExtensions "1.4" --private-config-path C:\Users\Desktop\jason\protected.json
info:    Executing command vm extension set
+ Getting virtual machines
+ Updating vm extension
info:    vm extension set command OK
```

After it **completed**, we can use new password to login the VM(please try to use **FQDN** to login this VM:xxxx.cloudapp.net).

By the way, if the error occurs again, please use PowerShell to check the ProvisionGuestAgent value:

```
Add-AzureAccount
$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'MyServiceName' -Name 'MyVMName'
$vm.GetInstance().ProvisionGuestAgent
```

If the value is not set to "true", we should use the flow command to set the ProvisionGuestAgent to “True”:

```
$vm.GetInstance().ProvisionGuestAgent = $true
```

> Any hints on how to recover the data from the VM? Or to recover the
>   access to the VM?

If you want to recover the data from the VM, we can create another VM2, then delete this VM(keep disk), and mount the disk to VM2, in this way, we can copy the data to new VM.
Also we can **add new user** to vm1's /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow and /etc/group. after that complete, we can use this VHD to create a new VM, same as your previously.

Comment: I had mentioned that "the CLI doesn't work due to lack if Provision Guest Agent"

Comment: @ppaulojr please check your vm ProvisionGuestAgent with powershell, `Add-AzureAccount
$vm = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName 'MyServiceName' -Name 'MyVMName'
$vm.GetInstance().ProvisionGuestAgent`  make sure the value is true.